# Error c2872 Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, templates

I keep having this issue with this program involving templates. I apologize for posting the entire code, but it's extremely short. The problem I keep having is it claims there's an error in c2872.

driver.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pair.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    pair<char> letters('a', 'd');
    cout << "\nThe first letter is: " << letters.getFirst();
    cout << "\nThe second letter is: " << letters.getSecond();

    cout << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Class .cpp file

```
#include "pair.h"

template <class T>
pair<T>::pair(const T& first, const T& second)
{
    f = first;
    s = second;
}

template<class T>
T pair<T>::getFirst() const
{
    return first;
}

template<class T>
T pair<T>::getSecond() const
{
    return second;
}

template<class T>
void pair<T>::setFirst(const T& first, const T& second)
{
    T temp = first;
    first = second;
    second = temp;
}
```

header file

```
template <class T>
class pair
{
private:
    T f;
    T s;
public:
    pair(const T&, const T&);
    T getFirst() const;
    T getSecond() const;
    void setFirst(const T&, const T&);
};
```

Comment: You can't separate template declarations and implementations.  Put the implementation in the header file so that `driver.cpp` can generate all the code it needs in compile-time.  Also, `getFirst()` and `getSecond()` are returning non-members (I think you meant `f` and `s`).

Comment: Also, it is useful to post the whole error message you are getting, instead of just "C2872".

Comment: Error 1 error C2872: 'pair' : ambiguous symbol c:\users\dale nelson\documents\uvu college stuff\cs 1410 class docs\labs\lab13\lab13\source.cpp 8 1 Lab13

Answer (score 1):

There is already `std::pair`. Since you also go `using namespace std;`, the issue could be that compiler cannot tell whether you mean `std::pair` or your `pair`.

To fix this, either stop doing `using namespace std;` , or call your pair something else. Preferably both!

Comment: And put your `pair` class in a namespace.

Comment: How would you do that? I've never seen that before.

Comment: I don't think `<iostream>` includes `<utility>`, so shouldn't it not be concerned about `std::pair`?

Comment: Any standard header is allowed to include any other standard header

Comment: I only mean to ask that, while this is a problem, it may not necessarily be the error being reported (yet).  If it's a linker error, it's because it cant find `pair`'s definition.  If it's a compiler error, it's a namespace issue.

Comment: He's posted the message now

Answer (score 1):

First, delete `pair.cpp` because [templates can't be defined in separate source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).  Next, replace `pair.h` with this concatenated source from `pair.cpp`.

Pair.h

```
namespace notstd {

template <class T>
class pair
{
private:
    T f;
    T s;
public:
    pair(const T&, const T&);
    T getFirst() const;
    T getSecond() const;
    void setFirst(const T&, const T&);
};

template <class T>
pair<T>::pair(const T& first, const T& second)
{
    f = first;
    s = second;
}

template<class T>
T pair<T>::getFirst() const
{
    //return first; //possible error?
    return f;
}

template<class T>
T pair<T>::getSecond() const
{
    //return second; //possible error?
    return s;
}

template<class T>
void pair<T>::setFirst(const T& first, const T& second)
{
    T temp = first;
    first = second;
    second = temp;
}

} //end namespace notstd
```

Finally, delete `using namespace std` and add `using notstd::pair`, OR prepend all `pair` with `notstd::pair`.